# OR query in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to perform a query on my elastic search dataset. My goal is to get all record that match any one of the criteria, so basically a bunch of OR's. Here is what my query looks like:

```
{
  "query" : {
    "filtered" : {
      "query" : {
        "match_all":{}
      }, 
      "filter" : { 
        "or" : [
          {"match" : {"field1" : ["value1", "value1.5"]}}, 
          {"match" : {"field2" : ["value2", "value2.5"]}}, 
          {"match" : {"field3" : ["value3", "value3.5"]}}, 
          {"match" : {"field4" : ["value4", "value4.5"]}}
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Field1-Field4 are all stored as arrays in elastic search. I need to get all results where any of the query values match any of the values in the stored array.

And I need to return the result if anything matches between them.
Can anyone point out what is wrong with this? I am not getting any results when I know they are there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're using `match` as type of filter, that doesn't exist afaik. 
Instead with your current setup you could use `terms` instead. 
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/terms-query/

SO:

```
{
  "query" : {
    "filtered" : {
      "query" : {
        "match_all":{}
      }, 
      "filter" : { 
        "or" : [
          {"terms" : {"field1" : ["value1", "value1.5"]}}, 
          {"terms" : {"field2" : ["value2", "value2.5"]}}, 
          {"terms" : {"field3" : ["value3", "value3.5"]}}, 
          {"terms" : {"field4" : ["value4", "value4.5"]}}
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Note: You're mixing up queries and filters. The `match` query does exist, but the `match` filter doesn't.

Comment: Sloppy. Thanks for pointing it out. Updated the initial explanation.